# In a parallel scrollview, the right scrollview scrolls anywhere

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

[image: issue Example.gif]

[image: Compare Width.png]

```
private func setUpContenViewConstraints(_ contenView: UIView, _ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        contenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        contenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        contenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        contenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        contenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)
    ])
    
    let heightConstraint = contenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor, constant: 1)
    heightConstraint.priority = .init(1)
    heightConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leftScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            leftScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            leftScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            leftScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rightScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
//            rightScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: waitingScrollView.trailingAnchor),
            rightScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            rightScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            rightScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
```

The current problematic structure is that the right ScrollView does not scroll only vertically when there are two UIScrollViews inside a UIView in parallel. I want both scrollviews to scroll only vertically. The used constraint condition is the same as the code block.

It is identified as a problem caused by the difference between the width of the scrollview and the width of the contentview when it is onScrolled. But I'm not sure which one part is contributing to these issues.

I would like the right scrollview to be able to scroll only vertically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit a really weird bug...

Assume running this on an `iPhone 14 Pro`, with the custom view holding the scroll views the full width of the main view (the screen).

That Width of the view is `393` ... when we create scroll views (or any view) each constrained to `width * 0.5`, each view's width should be `196.5`.

However, if we're on a `@3x` device, UIKit won't do that because it doesn't want to use (or *can't* use) partial pixels.

So, the width of the Left scroll view ends up being `196.6666...` and the Right scroll view is `196.3333....`.

We wouldn't ***expect*** that to be a problem, because the code is setting the "content view" widths equal to the scroll view `.frameLayoutGuide` widths (correctly), and the Left/Right content views get those `196.6666....` / `196.3333....` values respectively.

However!!!!

If we log the widths (SV is scroll view, CV is content view, CS is scroll view `.contentSize.width`) we see this:

```
Left SV Width: 196.66666666666666
Left CV Width: 196.66666666666666
Left CS Width: 196.66666666666666

Right SV Width: 196.33333333333334
Right CV Width: 196.33333333333334
Right CS Width: 196.66666666666666
```

Ugh -- the right scroll view content size width is `.3333....` ***greater than*** it should be.

If we run this on an `@2x` device, we won't experience the issue.

Or, if we constrain the view holding the two scroll views to an even-number width, we don't see the issue.

---

**Edit**

***I*** would call this a **bug** ... but maybe it's just an unfortunate side-effect of the fact that Floating-Point numbers cannot be accurately expressed.

Much like this code:

```
    let v1: CGFloat = 1.2
    let v2: CGFloat = 1.1 + 0.1
    print("v1:", v1, "v2:", v2, "Equal?", v1 == v2)
```

will output this to the debug console:

```
v1: 1.2 v2: 1.2000000000000002 Equal? false
```

One way I see to get around this specific issue is to make the scroll view widths whole numbers, and let them overlap by 1-point in the center.

Quick example...

**`UIView` subclass:**

```
class SideBySideView: UIView {
    
    let leftScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let rightScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let leftContentView = UIView()
    let rightContentView = UIView()

    private var leftWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        [leftScrollView, rightScrollView, leftContentView, rightContentView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        addSubview(leftScrollView)
        addSubview(rightScrollView)
        
        leftScrollView.addSubview(leftContentView)
        rightScrollView.addSubview(rightContentView)
        
        leftContentView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        rightContentView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        leftScrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        rightScrollView.backgroundColor = .blue

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leftScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            leftScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            leftScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rightScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            rightScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            rightScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

            rightScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftScrollView.widthAnchor),
        ])

        // initialize leftWidthConstraint ... the actual constant will be set in layoutSubviews
        leftWidthConstraint = leftScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
        leftWidthConstraint.isActive = true

        setUpContenViewConstraints(leftContentView, leftScrollView)
        setUpContenViewConstraints(rightContentView, rightScrollView)

    }
    
    private func setUpContenViewConstraints(_ contenView: UIView, _ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            contenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            contenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            contenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            contenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        let heightConstraint = contenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor, constant: 1)
        heightConstraint.priority = .init(1)
        heightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    
    // for tracking width changes
    private var boundsWidth: CGFloat = -1
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // we only want to execute this code if the bounds width has changed
        if boundsWidth != bounds.width {
            boundsWidth = bounds.width
            leftWidthConstraint.constant = ceil(bounds.width * 0.5)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**Demonstration Controller:**

```
class SideBySideTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sideBySideView = SideBySideView()
        sideBySideView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(sideBySideView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            sideBySideView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sideBySideView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sideBySideView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sideBySideView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])

    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Another way to avoid the problem -- ***and*** avoid the additional width manipulations / overlapping -- is to add a `constant` to the content view width anchors.

In your `setUpContenViewConstraints(...)` func, change:

```
contenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
```

to:

```
contenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
    constant: 8.0),
```

The `constant` can really be any positive value... it will "narrow" the `.contentSize` while having no effect the visual representation.

So now the custom view class becomes:

```
class SideBySideView: UIView {
    
    let leftScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let rightScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let leftContentView = UIView()
    let rightContentView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        [leftScrollView, rightScrollView, leftContentView, rightContentView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        addSubview(leftScrollView)
        addSubview(rightScrollView)
        
        leftScrollView.addSubview(leftContentView)
        rightScrollView.addSubview(rightContentView)
        
        leftContentView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        rightContentView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        leftScrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        rightScrollView.backgroundColor = .blue

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leftScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            leftScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            leftScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            leftScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rightScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            rightScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            rightScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            rightScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        setUpContenViewConstraints(leftContentView, leftScrollView)
        setUpContenViewConstraints(rightContentView, rightScrollView)

    }
    
    private func setUpContenViewConstraints(_ contenView: UIView, _ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            
            // use positive value for trailingAnchor constant
            contenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            
            contenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            contenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            contenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        let heightConstraint = contenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor, constant: 1)
        heightConstraint.priority = .init(1)
        heightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    
}
```

No need to manipulate the width constraints, and no need for `layoutSubviews()`.